# R notebook: rerunning chunks in different parts of code

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, chunks, rnotebook

Is there a way to rerun chunks in R notebook?

In knitr it is possible to rerun chunks simply by referencing their name. E.g. like this below, only the second chunk would output the result (source https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/reporting-with-r-markdown/chapter-two-embedding-code?ex=7).

````
```{r simple_sum, results = 'hide'}
 2 + 2
```


```{r ref.label='simple_sum', echo = FALSE}
```
````

Is there a simple way to do the same thing in the R notebook environment?